# DNS Lookup issues

Tags: php, dns

I am using this code

```
$dnsarr = dns_get_record($hostname,DNS_ALL);
$dnsarr2 = dns_get_record($hostname2,DNS_CNAME);
$mytest = dns_get_record($hostname,DNS_ALL,$authns, $addtl);
```

for DNS Lookup informations, but it gives me limited information. I want information like that found at http://www.intodns.com/google.com. How do I get all that information? Is there an API I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> i want informations like http://www.intodns.com/google.com. how i get all of these informations. do i get this by using some api? if yes, then which api i use for this?

You use the normal DNS API, just like they have, but you do it *lots of times*!